# Displacement map with css or html5

Tags: javascript, css, html, mockups

I use photoshop displacement maps to create mockups of t-shirts.  What is the simplest way to do this with code?  I've seen websites like placeit.net accomplish this.  How is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: I can't believe there aren't any answers for this yet after all this time.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: After a ton of searching I did find one resource for displacement maps with javascript.  http://www.soundstep.com/blog/2012/04/25/javascript-displacement-mapping/

Comment: have you go a workable solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SVG filter "Displacement Map".
https://yoksel.github.io/svg-filters/#/